# how to count the pixels between 0 to 10 and 240 to 255 for an image in opencv

Tags: opencv

How to count the pixels between 0 to 10 and 240 to 255 for an image in OpenCV using histograms

I tried this but couldn't get it. kindly help me please..

Comment: `int lower = 0; int middle=0; int upper = 0; for each pixel: {if(pixelVal<=10) lower++; if((pixelVal >= 240)&&(pixelVal <= 255)) upper++; if((pixelVal > 10)&&(pixelVal < 240)) middle++;}` which is some kind of simple histogram. If you want to use openCV histogram functions, have a look at http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html there you will have to change the "uniform" parameter to false and the "ranges". have a look at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html

Answer (score 4):

Forget histograms, use this instead:

```
Mat im = imread("myImage.jpg");
cvtColor(im,im,CV_BGR2GRAY);
cout << countNonZero((im<11)) << endl; // Number of pixels under 11 (0-10)
cout << countNonZero((im>239)) << endl; // Number of pixels over 239 (240-255)
```

Hope that it helps!